# adding href via javascript - bad MSIE bug?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it a bad practice to add href via javascript like below? In IE8, I'm seeing the status bar loading continuously even though the page has been updated and I suspect the below code is causing that to occur.

```
document.getElementById('sucessMsgId').innerHTML = 'Your profile has been updated. <a href='+xProfileUri+'>View Profile</a>';
```

What is the right way to do it? Does using jQuery to fix the above code could solve the IE status bar loading issue?

UPDATE: Found that the IE browser status loading continuously because it gets into this part of jQUery code and does not finish executing. This happens when I attach a load event to an iframe and only in IE8.

```
for ( i = 0; i < handlerQueue.length && !event.isPropagationStopped(); i++ ) {
            matched = handlerQueue[ i ];
            event.currentTarget = matched.elem;

            for ( j = 0; j < matched.matches.length && !event.isImmediatePropagationStopped(); j++ ) {
                handleObj = matched.matches[ j ];

                // Triggered event must either 1) be non-exclusive and have no namespace, or
                // 2) have namespace(s) a subset or equal to those in the bound event (both can have no namespace).
                if ( run_all || (!event.namespace && !handleObj.namespace) || event.namespace_re && event.namespace_re.test( handleObj.namespace ) ) {

                    event.data = handleObj.data;
                    event.handleObj = handleObj;

                    ret = ( (jQuery.event.special[ handleObj.origType ] || {}).handle || handleObj.handler )
                            .apply( matched.elem, args );

                    if ( ret !== undefined ) {
                        event.result = ret;
                        if ( ret === false ) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            event.stopPropagation();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: That's fine.  You're setting the `href` prior to injecting the `<a>` element.

Comment: Probably some analytics script which keep running

Comment: As of now, I believe its a MSIE bug http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320731 which is causing this issue, I will check the network tab though

Comment: dint find the network tab, used HTTPWatch, but there are not requests that are in progress when the status bar is showing progress, strongly believe it is due to the MS bug above but the work around specified does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to multiple events happening at the same time and the UI being updated with the success message at the same time. Delayed the update of UI by adding a setTimeout to the function call that updates the UI.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what `xProfileUri` contains. If it contains a URL in quotes, then it should be ok. Make sure to not forget the double quotes before and after the URI string. This can be done either in your innerHTML assignment string, or when you assign the URI value to `xProfileUri`.

**EDIT:** Suppose you have the following

```
var xProfileUri = 'http://google.com';
document.getElementById('successMsgId').innerHTML = 'Your profile has been updated. <a href='+xProfileUri+'>View Profile</a>';
```

This will output the following HTML:

```
Your profile has been updated <a href=http://google.com>View Profile</a>
```

But that `href` attribute is not properly formed, as it does not have double-quotes around it. Instead, make sure that you have one of the following:

```
var xProfileUri = '"http://google.com"';
//note the double quotes within the single quotes
```

OR

```
document.getElementById('successMsgId').innerHTML =
    'Your profile has been updated. <a href="'+xProfileUri+'">View Profile</a>';
//note the double quotes after the = sign and before the greater-than sign
```